# should be compatible with App\Http\Controllers\Controller::authorize($ability, $arguments = Array) - register controller error

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to send the form information to database but when i submit the form this error appears:
ErrorException
Declaration of App\Http\Controllers\LivroController::authorize() should be compatible with App\Http\Controllers\Controller::authorize($ability, $arguments = Array)

CONTROLLER (LivroController)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\StoreUpdateLivro;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Livro;

class LivroController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    protected $request;
    private $repository;
    private $livro;

    public function __construct(Livro $livro)
    {
        $this->livro = $livro;
    }
        
    

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
    
   /* public function index()*/
  //  {
       /* $title = 'listagem dos livros';
        $livros = $this->livro->all();
        return view ('livros/cadastro', compact('livros','title'));*/
      //  return view ('livros/cadastro');

        
  //  } 

    
    protected function validator(Request $request)
    {
        return Validator::make($request, [
            'namel' => ['required', 'string', 'max:200'],
            'autor' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:200'],
            'editora' => ['required', 'string', 'max:50'],
            'categoria'=> ['required', 'string', 'min:50'],
            'classificação'=> ['required', 'string', 'min:1','max:2'],
            'descricao'=> ['required', 'string', 'min:200'],
            'image'=> ['not required'],
  
        ]);
    }

     /**
      * Store a newly created resource in storage.
      *
      * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
      * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
      */
    public function create(StoreUpdateLivro $request)
    {
        
        $user = Auth::user()->id;
        $data = $request->all();

        if($request->image->isValid()){

           $image = $request->image->store('livros');
           $data['image'] = $image;
        }
        Livro::create([
            'users_id' => $user,
            'namel' => $request['namel'],
            'autor' => $request['autor'],
            'editora' => $request['editora'],
            'categoria'=> $request['categoria'],
            'classificação'=>$request['classificação'] ,
            'descricao'=>$request['descricao'],
            'image'=>$request['image'],
        ]);
        return view('livros/cadastro');

        
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $livro = DB::select('select * from livros');
        return view('livros/mostrar_livros', [
            'livro' => $livro,
        ]);
    }



    
    

}
```

Comment: Hi, can I see your `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` file?

Comment: '<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `authorize()` method from `LivroController` and then,
go to `StoreUpdateLivro` file and set return true into `authorize()` method.
and also you don't need to `validator` method in your controller.

See more about the [FormRequest](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation) in Laravel.

Comment: thank you!!! That worked, but when I submit the form an error appears on image upload: "The image must be an image.". I don't know why laravel is not validating this image, i already tried ".jpg" , ".jpeg" and ".png". Can you help me?

Comment: I already tried to add  " enctype="multipart/form-data" " on my form.

Comment: I think you should do it in this way: `$request->file('image')->isValid()`

Comment: I'm sorry, I've forgotten to mark. I will try in this way

Comment: It didn't work... Don't have another way to fix it? I really don't how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have a copy/paste problem

Delete LivroController:: authorize() method - you copied it from Form Request - and all will be work fine.

Comment: This solution worked for that error but now I have 403 error- "this action is unauthorized".